# Select Storyboard Based On Condition In WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, wpf-animation

I have a Border control and when the mouse is clicked on it I would like the Border's background to turn green momentarily if the "IsLeft" property from my view model is true.  If "IsLeft" is false, I would like the background to turn red momentarily.

I have one storyboard for the green animation, and a second storyboard for the red animation.

I think I need to combine an EventTrigger (for the mouse click) and DataTrigger (bound to IsLeft) to do this, but I'm not sure how.

Note that I also have an MVVM Relay Command to perform some logic in the ViewModel when the border is clicked.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTestBase.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTestBase"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
    xmlns:Custom="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
    xmlns:h="clr-namespace:WpfTestBase.Helpers"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    DataContext="{Binding Path=Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="StoryboardCorrect">
        <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.IsEnabled)">
            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="False"/>
            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="True"/>
        </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
            <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="#00FF00"/>
            <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="LightBlue"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <h:CommandFakeAnimation Duration="0:0:0" Command="{Binding Path=FakeAnimationCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="StoryboardWrong">
        <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.IsEnabled)">
            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="False"/>
            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="True"/>
        </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
            <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="#FF0000"/>
            <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="LightBlue"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <h:CommandFakeAnimation Duration="0:0:0" Command="{Binding Path=FakeAnimationCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Canvas>
    <Viewbox Canvas.Left="025" Canvas.Top="57">
        <Border x:Name="border" Width="200" Height="82" Canvas.Left="098" Canvas.Top="93" BorderThickness="6,8,7,8" 
                BorderBrush="Black" Background="LightBlue">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                    <Custom:EventToCommand Command="{Binding BorderCommand, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <Border.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.MouseLeftButtonUp">
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource StoryboardCorrect}"/>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Border.Triggers>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CountModel.Word}"/>
        </Border>
    </Viewbox>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" Canvas.Left="312" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="IsLeft:" Canvas.Top="188"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock2" Canvas.Left="348" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding IsLeft}" Canvas.Top="188"/>

</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of dynamically selecting a `Storyboard`, you can use a single `Storyboard` but bind your `DiscreteColorKeyFrame.Value` DependencyProperty to your `IsLeft` property and then use an `IValueConverter` to convert the value to the appropriate color.

The converter would look something like this:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(System.Windows.Media.Color))]
public class IsLeftToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((bool)value) ? System.Windows.Media.Color.Green : System.Windows.Media.Color.Red
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Your XAML could then look something like this:

```
    <Border x:Name="border" Width="200" Height="82" Canvas.Left="098" Canvas.Top="93" BorderThickness="6,8,7,8" 
            BorderBrush="Black" Background="LightBlue">
        <Border.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.MouseLeftButtonUp">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.IsEnabled)">
                            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="False"/>
                            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="True"/>
                        </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                            <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{Binding IsLeft, Converter={StaticResource IsLeftToColorConverter}}"/>
                            <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="LightBlue"/>
                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <h:CommandFakeAnimation Duration="0:0:0" Command="{Binding Path=FakeAnimationCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Border.Triggers>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CountModel.Word}"/>
    </Border>
```